# Python: print NameError

Tags: python, nameerror

```
import math 
r_out = int(input("Insert rings outside raadius: ")) 
r_in = int(input("Insert rings inner raadius: "))

# ring size calculating function
def areaOfRing(r_out, r_in):
    r_outs = (r_out**2)*math.pi
    r_ins = (r_in**2)*math.pi
    ring_size  = r_outs - r_ins
    return ring_size

ring_size = areaOfRing 
print('Ring size is = ',ring_size)
```

I tried to print out the answer as it should do when you put the 2 numbers inside. After I made it run I got a `NameError`. Yes. I did tried `ring_size = areaOfRing()`, and `ring_size = areaOfRing(r_out, r_in)` gave me both errors.

(Note, After I restarted the program, it started to work with @ Martijn's help).

Comment: I have made one correction to your code that would otherwise have given you a syntax error. What is the **full** error message, traceback included? Please [edit] your question to add that.

Comment: Besides the fact that your returning the function instead of running it on the user inputted data, this is working fine I see no errors

Comment: @yuvi: *provided* you pass in the `r_out` and `r_in` arguments to the function call of course.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah, it's still working with no errors.

Comment: @yuvi: the question is terrible; as it stands it should be closed. What if the OP did call the function with the wrong arguments?

Comment: @MartijnPieters that definitly seems to be the problem. His variables are really easy to confuse with one another, r_outs and r_out, r_ins and r_in

Comment: @yuvi: No, the problem is that there is no `import math` and the OP then stopped calling the function. See a comment on one of the answers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you're right. Weird though, I copy-pasted it to sublime and it worked right away. Maybe I added it without noticing

Comment: I am not the brightest one.

Comment: It would have helped if you had shown us the *full* error message; `NameError` by itself doesn't tell us much. *What* name was not found is an important detail, and the traceback would have told us *tons* more about where the error happened and how Python got there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to supply `arguments` while calling function.

```
import math


# ring size calculating function
def areaOfRing(r_out, r_in):
    r_outs = (r_out**2)*math.pi
    r_ins = (r_in**2)*math.pi
    ring_size  = r_outs - r_ins
    return ring_size

r_out = int(input("Insert rings outside raadius: ")) 
r_in = int(input("Insert rings inner raadius: "))

ring_size = areaOfRing(r_out, r_in) 
print('Ring size is = ',ring_size)
```

Comment: Don't use input, use raw_input (unless in python 3.x)

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much, but..

you forgot the import math

Lasttime i put ring_size = areaOfRing(r_out, r_in)  , it gave me wierd <A0EBDED> error.


Bow.

Comment: @LabKitty: That is because you are printing the *function object*, you need to call it to get a result.

Comment: @ Martijn: I never tought of it. Thank you!

Comment: @yuvi: He is using `Python3` as he is using `print()`

Comment: @sachitad print() is valid python 2 syntax

Comment: Yup it is, but usually people with `python2` uses `print` only. That was a wild guess, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling your function properly, do this:

```
ring_size = areaOfRing(r_out, r_in)
```

Comment: That doesn't explain the `NameError`.

Comment: Fix **what** problem? Sure, it makes the code posted here work, but that is **not** what the OP is asking about.